# Installing pdfcrop command-line tool on Mac

Tags: texlive, mac, pdfcrop

I would like to do some PDF cropping at the command line.  I've installed BasicTeX and the TeX Live Utility:

```
brew cask install basictex
brew cask install tex-live-utility
```

I then opened up the TeX Live Utility and used it to install the `pdfcrop` and `texlive-scripts-extra` packages:

[image]

However, I don't see a `pdfcrop` in my PATH anywhere.

Is there something else I need to install, or is `pdfcrop` already installed somewhere I haven't noticed?

Comment: Look for `pdfcrop` under TeX Live Utilities' Packages Tab and make sure the x86_64-darwin (assuming you are using a recent OS version) version is, in fact, installed. Make sure you have ghostscript installed too since pdfcrop needs it.

Comment: @HerbSchulz yes, it's installed, according to the TeX Live UI.  I'll add a little screenshot to my question.

Comment: If you type `which pdfcrop` in a Terminal what do you get?

Comment: Try `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall pdfcrop`

Comment: @AlanMunn I get `pdfcrop not found`, as expected, since there is no `pdfcrop` in my PATH.  In what directory did you expect it to have been installed?

Comment: It should be in `/Library/texbin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `pdfcrop` installed in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Apparently the BasicTeX installer changes the user's path (actually, for all users of the system) by putting an entry in the `/etc/paths.d` directory:

```
% cat /etc/paths.d/TeX         
/Library/TeX/texbin
```

There was no indication during installation that my `PATH` was being modified, so I assumed it wasn't.  But after opening a new login shell, the new path entry from `/etc/paths.d/TeX` is seen, and now `pdfcrop` (and lots of other stuff in `/Library/TeX/texbin`) is available.

Comment: This is correct, but then somehow your path has been set incorrectly. Maybe this is a consequence of installing via `homebrew`? With a standard MacTeX installation, the path is set correctly.

Comment: I installed BasicTeX, not MacTeX.  All Homebrew does is download the standard BasicTeX installer and run it, which didn't give me any output that it was changing my `PATH`.  I also noticed no changes to my `~/.zshrc` and friends.  However, I eventually discovered that it *did* change my path - I'll put the details in this answer.

Comment: BasicTeX is still MacTeX just much smaller.

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for `pdfcrop` on Mac, `brew cask install mactex` will get you this. No other changes needed.

Comment: Install command is now `brew install --cask mactex` (brew made some changes start of 2021 to how cask works)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid installing megabytes of mactex by downloding PDFCrop directly from here:

[PDFCrop](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcrop/)

Once you have extracted the content, in the mail folder there is the executable. Run it over your file directly from the command line.

Tried on MacOS BigSur, M1.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know.

Comment: It is not the script that is given with tex package

Answer (score 0):

I first upvoted Gabrer's answer and now cannot undo my upvote - this executable doesn't work. It pretends it works by simply not printing anything to the command line, but it doesn't work. What you have to do to make it work:

- `brew install --cask basictex`
- `brew install --cask tex-live-utility`
- `brew install ghostscript`
- Open TeX Live Utility, go to packages and install `pdfcrop`
- Open new terminal window - you now have pdfcrop